Ubuntu 22.04 does not recognize emtpy DVD
I have a PC with Ubuntu 22.04.
This is lshw
root@localhost:/etc# lshw -C disk
*-disk                    
   description: ATA Disk
   product: SAMSUNG MZ7LN256
   physical id: 0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: 100Q
   serial: S2MJNX0J622395
   size: 238GiB (256GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=6c8b2c98
*-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: DVD-RW SH-216AB
   vendor: TSSTcorp
   physical id: 1
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: LE03
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc

this is inixi
 Optical-1: /dev/sr0 vendor: TSSTcorp model: DVD-RW SH-216AB rev: LE03
   dev-links: cdrom
 Features: speed: 40 multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes
    rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running

When I put a CD into it, then it recognized, and I can see the list of files.
But, when I put a DVD into it, even if data on it or not, ubuntu does not recognize it.
I saw a lot of posts about it from "your device dying" to "edit fstab", but I really don't get it, what is the problem, how could I solve it.
If you have any question, write it in comments.
EDIT:
sudo journalctl  --follow:
There are no new entries, zero, nothing...

Watch sudo journalctl  --follow as you insert a DVD, to get data to [edit] into your question,  selectively.

@waltinator sadly, nada, naker, nothing :( it's a renewed lenovo thinkcentre m81 machin, works like a charm, this is the only problem.
